# manipulating pseudo elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ive been trying to change the selection colour of content dynamically with javascript from within the html but cant seem to get it to work. Ideally Id like to change the section colour to be one out of any array...

```
var colors = Array("#A3F8EF", "#FF7275", "#CBB6E7", "#FF9D74", "#FDF874"), idx;
```

but I cant even get it to change the selection colour to a single differnt colour. The code I am trying is:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('html::-moz-selection {background-color: #FDF874;}',0);    
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('html::selection {background-color: #FDF874;}',0);    
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('html::-webkit-selection {background-color: #FDF874;}',0);
```

any ideas would be great

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors? I'm guessing javascript still can't parse pseudo selectors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're getting an exception parsing one of those prefixed rules, and so the code adding the others doesn't get run. If you put them in a `try/catch`, it works: *(I also changed the tag name from `html` to `*`)*

The following, for instance, works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11:

```js
var colors = ["#A3F8EF", "#FF7275", "#CBB6E7", "#FF9D74", "#FDF874"];
setRandomSelectionColor();

function setRandomSelectionColor() {
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  var color = colors[n];
  
  try {
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("*::-moz-selection {background-color: " + color + ";}", 0);
  }
  catch (e) {
  }
  try {
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("*::selection {background-color: " + color + ";}", 0);
  }
  catch (e) {
  }
  try {
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("*::-webkit-selection {background-color: " + color + ";}", 0);
  }
  catch (e) {
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Select your text here!</p>
```

---

**Original Answer** *(before I got curious why it was failing)*:

I didn't have any luck with `insertRule`, but you can dynamically create and replace a `style` element: *(I also changed the tag name from `html` to `*`)*

This works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11:

```js
var colors = ["#A3F8EF", "#FF7275", "#CBB6E7", "#FF9D74", "#FDF874"];
setRandomSelectionColor();
$("input").on("click", setRandomSelectionColor);

function setRandomSelectionColor() {
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  var color = colors[n];
  
  $("#the-style").remove();
  $("<style id='the-style'>\n" +
    "*::-moz-selection {background-color: " + color + ";}" +
    "*::selection {background-color: " + color + ";}" +
    "*::-webkit-selection {background-color: " + color + ";}" +
    "</style>").appendTo('head');
}
```

```html
<p>Select your text here!</p>
<input type="button" value="New Random Color">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```